# Best way to edit filtered array after searching with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, uisearchcontroller

I've currently got a UITableViewController with an array of Memories (which is a struct with two variables - memoryTitle and memoryDescription). Amongst didSelectRowAt, I've got it running the following function to allow the user to edit the item.

```
func configure(memory: Memory, position: Int) {
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddMemoryViewController") as? AddMemoryViewController else {
        fatalError("Unable to create AddMemoryViewController")
    }

selectedMemory = position
vc.delegate = self
vc.memory = memory
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

}

Once they've finished editing, my AddMemoryViewController sends the data back to it's delegate (which is my original table view) and updates the memory with the following code:

```
  func update(memory: Memory) {
        guard let selectedMemory = selectedMemory else { return }

        memories[selectedMemory] = memory
        saveData()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

This has been working fine, but now I'm trying to implement a UISearchController on my original table view. The current way I'm trying to use is by having an array of filteredMemories. If I use the filteredMemories and try and edit one of those items, I'm not sure how to update the original item again (since the index of the item is different between each array). I think the answer lies somewhere in changing Memories to a class (so filteredMemories and memories are editing the same object) but it'd be great if anyone could lend some guidance to how to approach this problem please?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already take a look at `IndexSet`, to store the index values of the filtered data? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset

Comment: I hadn't thought of that - thank you. Do you mean to store the original index values (as in what they were in the original memory array)? So then I'd know how the replace the 'master' version? Sorry if that's an obvious question - still reasonably new to Swift!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `IndexSet`, you could do the following.
Given the following data:

```
var dataArray = ["A1", "B1", "A2", "C1", "C2", "A3"]
//                0     1     2     3     4     5

// filter for "A*", here hard coded, in real live you would
// calculate it dynamically:
var index : IndexSet = [0,2,5] // Index of "A*" in dataArray

// Example: get data for row == 2
var dataIndex = index[2] // 5
var data = dataArray[dataIndex] // "A3"
```

So:

- When filtering, store the matching indexes of the original array into the `IndexSet`
- `numberOfRows` will return the count of the index set
- `cellForRow` will retrieve the original index from the index set, get the corresponding entry from the original array, and configure the cell

  - So for `row==2`, get `dataArray[index[2]]`
- Update will do the same: get the index, then get the data